# iOS Status Bar Height Incorrect when In a Call

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, statusbar

I'm seeing an issue where if a user opens my app while they are in a call, or doing something else that causes the status bar to be double-height, the entire layout gets pushed down by the height of the status bar.

For example, if the user enters a call and they are *already in the app*, then the layout will look like this:

[image]

However, if a user is already in a call and they enter the app, the layout will look like this (the nav bar being cut off at the bottom of the image is part of the issue, not a problem with the screenshot):

[image]

All of my layouts have been created through a StoryBoard and are using AutoLayout.  I have also recently reviewed and fixed any AutoLayout constraints that seemed to be bad or out of place.

If anyone has guidance about what might be going on, or a way to fix this, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main view controller, where your tab bar controller lives, make sure you override viewDidLayoutSubviews() and resize the UITabBarController as such:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.myTabViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to tweak it a little for my view structure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews{
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Comment: No luck.  I also tried calling `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` before calling this and still nothing.